# How to style select list Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to style Select List from Angular Material:

```
 <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
```

For example, I need to make border and add arrow on the right corner.

How to do this in Material, just to modify CSS file or does exist special approach?

Comment: You need to put border around each option or the select panel? Does the arrow in the right corner do anything, or just an icon?

Comment: I tried to set CSS for `mat-select-placeholder` as` {display: none !important;}` It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify (or include your own new) CSS file that has the required design changes.

`select` boxes can be tricky to stylize and an `md-menu` offers more flexibility if you require it.

Comment: I try to changes CSS styles in style.css of components file like this: `.mat-tab-label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}`. But it does not repalce Angular Material styles.

Comment: You can use `background-color: #eeeeee !important;` to force the override. I can't be sure your class naming is correct from the information in the question though.